# Swift/Swinject without Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swinject

I'm starting a new Swift project using Swinject **without** Storyboards. What's the pattern to inject ViewControllers into other ViewControllers to perform Segues?

- If you inject a child ViewController into a parent ViewController, won't the child ViewController always be the same instance when you segue to it and back to the parent? I want to create a new one every time.
- If you inject a child ViewController into a parent, won't that cause child ViewControllers of that child ViewController to also be injected, meaning you will get the entire app loaded into memory when you load the root ViewController?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Without code it's very hard to answer you. Both of your questions depends on how you are implementing the hierarchy parent-children.

Comment: Not sure what exacly you mean with "inject". In general, do what you normally see in Storyboard in code but without segues. Create `UINavigationController`, instantiate `UIViewController` and set it a `rootViewController`. Instead of seque, use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(...)`.